# Calculation only happens on 2nd digit entered

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a calculation as I type it into an entry box but it isn't working. It completely ignores the latest digit I put in and will only calculate the ones before it. Here is the relevant code:

```
def CalculateWeight(event):
                x = int(CWeightBox.get()) - int(EWeightBox.get())
                    
                NWeightBox.config(state='normal')
                NWeightBox.delete(0, 'end')
                NWeightBox.insert(0, x)
                NWeightBox.config(state='disable')

CWeightBox = ttk.Entry(Frame1)
CWeightBox.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
CWeightBox.bind("<Key>", CalculateWeight)

EWeightBox = ttk.Entry(Frame1)
EWeightBox.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)


NWeightBox = ttk.Entry(Frame1, state=DISABLED)
NWeightBox.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: the thing is that `"<Key>"` event is called before the entry box is updated with the new character or sth so basically you can simply use the `"<KeyRelease>"` event to allow the character be entered and only calculate on release

Comment: That worked! Thank you!